# CSS selectors for specific pages

Tags: theming

I'm working on a custom theme which involves styling specific pages and nodes. At first, to target these specific nodes, I used the selector page-node-##, where ## is the node ID. But this was on my local machine, and when I exported these nodes, I found that the node IDs would be different on both the staging and production servers. Is it better to use the section-XX, selector instead?

I was wondering if there is a recommended CSS selector for this kind of use cases, where the CSS is applied on specific pages/nodes?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this using [context](https://drupal.org/project/context):

Under conditions select `Path` and input your path

then under Reactions select `Theme HTML`.  Here you can select the class you wish to add to the body.